# Flex multiple remote object call

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, blazeds, flex-mobile

I've a problem with multiple remote object calls. So that firstly I must retrieve employerID's from server (using BlazeDS btw), secondly I must make a request for each employerID and retrieve other details for EACH employer (another 2 remote object calls for each employerID) according there employerID's. So as you understood 3rd remote object call will take the 2nd's response as its parameter, and the 2nd one will take 1st's response as parameter.

My problem is that when I iterate through the response of first request it call's the 2nd remote object only for its last element not for each.

Here's my view code:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <parsley:FastInject property="karBUS" type="{KarBUS}"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="hastalariGetirResponder" result="hastalariGetirResponder_resultHandler(event)"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="yatakOdaGetirResponder" result="yatakOdaGetirResponder_resultHandler(event)" fault="yatakOdaGetirResponder_faultHandler(event)"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="hastaKartlariGetirResponder" result="hastaKartlariGetirResponder_resultHandler(event)"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="hastaResimGetirResponder" result="hastaResimGetirResponder_resultHandler(event)"/>
        <parsley:Configure  />
    </fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

[Inject(id="karBUS")]
public var karBUS:KarBUS;

            protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {


                trace("Hastalarim View: persID:"+SessionClientData.prsnl.personelId+",servisID: " + SessionClientData.servisId);
                hastalariGetirResponder.token = karBUS.getHastalarim(SessionClientData.prsnl.personelId,SessionClientData.servisId);

            }

protected function hastalariGetirResponder_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                hastalarim = hastalariGetirResponder.lastResult;

                if(hastalarim.length == 0) {
                    this.addElement(txt_empty);
                    this.removeElement(busy_ind);
                }

                for(var i:int=0;i<hastalarim.length;i++){

                    kt = hastalarim.getItemAt(i) as Object;

                    vizitID = kt[6];
                    hastaTC = kt[3];

                    yatakOdaGetirResponder.token = karBUS.getYatakOdaNo(vizitID);
                }

            }


protected function yatakOdaGetirResponder_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                yatakOda = yatakOdaGetirResponder.lastResult as Object;

                hastaKartlariGetirResponder.token = karBUS.getHastaKarti(vizitID);

            }

            protected function hastaKartlariGetirResponder_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                hastaTuru = hastaKartlariGetirResponder.lastResult as String;

                hastaResimGetirResponder.token = karBUS.getHastaResim(hastaTC);
            }

            protected function hastaResimGetirResponder_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                resim = hastaResimGetirResponder.lastResult as ByteArray;


                dp=new ArrayCollection();

                var yatak:String;
                var oda:String;
                var kat:String;

                if(yatakOda == null){
                    yatak = "";
                    oda = "";
                    kat = "";
                }else{
                    yatak = yatakOda[2];
                    oda = yatakOda[1];
                    kat = yatakOda[0];
                }

                for(var i:int=0;i<hastalarim.length;i++){

                    kt = hastalarim.getItemAt(i) as Object;

                    var dt:Date = kt[5] as Date;
                    var vizitT:String = dt.date + "-" + (dt.month+1) + "-" + dt.fullYear;

                    dp.addItem({hastaId:kt[0], adi:kt[1],soyadi:kt[2],tcKimlikNo:kt[3], resim: resim,
                        yasi:kt[4],katNo:kat,odaNo:oda,yatakNo:yatak,
                        vizitTarihi:vizitT,vizitId:kt[6],cinsiyeti:kt[7], hastaTuru:hastaTuru});


                    trace("OdaNO - Yatak NO: "+ oda + ", " + yatak);

                }






            }



    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

How can I make flex threads wait until the previous one returns a response? any thread handling method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are overwriting the token everytime

```
for(var i:int=0;i<hastalarim.length;i++){
   ...    
   yatakOdaGetirResponder.token = karBUS2.getYatakOdaNo(vizitID);
}
```

so only the response for the last request is handled.

You should not use the static responder `yatakOdaGetirResponder`, but create a new `CallResponder` object for every request.

```
for(var i:int=0;i<hastalarim.length;i++){
    ...    
    var responder: CallResponder = new CallResponder();
    responder.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,  yatakOdaGetirResponder_resultHandler);
    responder.token = karBUS2.getYatakOdaNo(vizitID);
}
```

Comment: Yes I've thought about this... Is there any way for creating a new token for each callresponder?! OR do I have to create different Call Responders each time before for iteration?!

Comment: Yes that was what I's gonna to do if there would be no alternatives..Now I'm gonna convert all static call responders to dynamical ones. But that was a good detail, & thank you splash!

Comment: One more question, is there any method to know that all 4 remote object calls are done in order to insert them into a list?! as I understood flex remote object call works in "queue" fashion - it puts every new call to a queue and after all calls them if result-handler that I have wrote them in is finished... Is there more upper class to inform us if all requests are done or something like that?!

Comment: @lbstr RemoteObject calls are asynchronous, so there are not queued (synchronous). You could count the number of requests and responses by yourself. If they are equal, then all requests should be done. :)

Comment: Too much problems with that asynchronous call...is not there any way to make it synchronous? Otherwise I have to create separate lists for each remote object call & keep them in classified way so that I could access empID=57 detail from detail1 or another detail from detail2 list etc.